# Highchart basic bar : How to know which specific bar section is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a highchart with following categories and series :

```
    xAxis: {
                categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Population (millions)',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            }


series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 1900',
            data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 2012',
            data: [1052, 954, 4250, 740, 38]
        }]
```

The pointer event let's me know which category is clicked. but how can i know which specific year is clicked. So let's say the user clicks on year 1900 under Africa then I want to know that the user clicked on category  : Africa and year 1900.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use plotOptions and inside that use below code to get respective items.

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            alert('Category: ' + this.category + '   value: ' + this.y + '  Year :' + this.series.name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

The working JSFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9or558uj/).

**this.category** : This will return the respective category name.

**this.y** : This will return the respective y-axis value(data).

**this.series.name** : This will return the respective series name.